# DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider containerType, modelType

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the difference between containerType and modelType in `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`'s `GetMetadataForProperties(..., Type containerType)`    and `GetMetadataForType(..., Type modelType)`. 
I'd also like to have examples of their values, e.g. for some imaginary "Edit" page with CustomerViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetMetadataForProperties` returns a `ModelMetadata` instance for each property found in the `containerType`.

So if you have:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
   [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
   // etc.
}
```

And this sample code:

```
var model = new CustomerViewModel();

var propertiesMetadata = provider.GetMetadataForProperties(model, model.GetType());

var customerName = propertiesMetadata.Where(m => m.PropertyName == "Name").First().DisplayName; // customerName would equal "Customer Name"
```

Whereas `GetMetadataForType` gets metadata for what is ostensibly the container itself.

Example:

```
var model = new CustomerViewModel();

var metadata = provider.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());

var customerName = metadata.Properties.Where(m => m.PropertyName == "Name").First().DisplayName; // customerName would equal "Customer Name"
```

This stuff is mostly used within the model binding, validation, and view engine internally.

In a view itself, you don't access these methods directly. Your view will already the `ModelMetadata` accessible. The following view (which uses `CustomerViewModel` as the model type) prints out a span with the display name for each property of the model.

```
@foreach (var propertyMetadata in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties) {
  <span>@propertyMetadata.DisplayName</span>
}

// the resulting HTML should be <span>Customer Name<span><span>Account Number</span>
```

Comment: Can you fix your second example, please.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a case, when containerType is not the same as modelType?

Comment: The reason they let you specify the type, I think, is so you can restrict retrieved metadata to a specific interface or base type. Basically, it just give consumers of `ModelMetadataProvider` more flexibility in edge cases. Most of the time containerType and modelType are the same, yes.